# See who's meeting with who in Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook

So, I can see people's calendar and their appointments. If two people have the same appointment at the same time, I know they are meeting, so the information is there.
However I cannot search who is meeting who...

I mean, I could try all the 10'000+ people in the company and see if they match...but no.
I also don't want to ask for a "shared calendar", which I believe will give me that information.

I simply think that the information is available to me, but I cannot search for it...

Is there any trick? or any add-ons that could do that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research and testing, I'm afraid this can't be implemented with the build-in feature in Outlook.

In Outlook, we (as organizers) can only use the tracking function to see the participation in the created meeting.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.